# Upload PDF Files PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

I am trying to upload only PDF files in my form, but nothing happens. It doesn't save the file name in the database and the file does not save into the directory.
My PHP code is

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

   $folder_path = 'health/';

   $filename = basename($_FILES['healthfile']['name']);
   $newname = $folder_path . $filename;

   if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['healthfile']['tmp_name'], $newname)) {
      if ($_FILES['healthfile']['type'] != "application/pdf") {

          echo "<p>Class notes must be uploaded in PDF format.</p>";
      } else {
          $filesql = "INSERT INTO tbl_health (link) VALUES ('{$filename}')".die(mysql_error());
          $fileresult = mysql_query($filesql, $con).die(mysql_error());
     }

     if ($fileresult) {
          echo 'Success';
     } else {
          echo 'fail';
     }
  }

}
```

my form is

```
<form action="allhealth.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <label>Upload Your Health Certificate</label>
    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
         Browse <input name="healthfile" type="file">
    </span>
    <br/><br/>
    <button type="button" name="submit" class="btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Please help!!

Comment: that's a unique `$filesql` you got going there

Comment: What does that mean? unique?

Comment: `.die(mysql_error())` is a syntax error. replace the dot with `or`. We also don't know which MySQL API you're connecting with. Also make sure the folder has proper permissions to write to.

Comment: use error reporting also. Make sure that file doesn't go over the max upload size

Comment: *I warmed up the espresso and popcorn machines a while ago* @Drew and all my comments not taken seriously.

Comment: crazier things have happened @Drew and won't stop here.

Comment: @Drew I wonder if everyone is enjoying their shot of (sql) injection. I rather a shot of espresso. But at this point, best to make it a double.

Comment: @Drew to think that if you or I would've submitted an answer... *wowzers.* Over 1/2 hour of them commenting back and forth. I'd of sent them a bill and at $125.00/hr, *minimum 1 hour.* ;-) Ok, I am outta here. *ciao!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $folder_path = 'health/';

    $filename = basename($_FILES['healthfile']['name']);
    $newname = $folder_path . $filename;

    $FileType = pathinfo($newname,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if($FileType == "pdf")
    {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['healthfile']['tmp_name'], $newname))
        {

            $filesql = "INSERT INTO tbl_health (link) VALUES('$filename')";
            $fileresult = mysql_query($filesql);

            if (isset($fileresult))
            {
                echo 'File Uploaded';
            } else
            {
                echo 'Something went Wrong';
            }
        }
        else
        {

            echo "<p>Upload Failed.</p>";
        }


    }
    else
    {
        echo "<p>Class notes must be uploaded in PDF format.</p>";
    }

}
```

> **Note** Before upload file you should check whether its in correct format
>
> **and `MySQL` extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQ`L extension should be used.**

Comment: No, once I click the submit button nothing happens

Comment: how about this `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {`

Comment: what if his isnt. Yours is

Comment: @Andrew is files getting upload??

Comment: After browsing the file and then clicked the submit button to upload the page stays as it is. It doesn't display any message and nothing is saved in the database and the folder

Comment: Yes, but the file doesn't get uploaded

Comment: It worked, Thanks, but the file name does not save into the database

Comment: @Andrew You want to store file name or complete path??

Comment: I want to store only the file name in my database

Comment: @Andrew use `INSERT INTO tbl_health (link) VALUES ($filename)`. and make sure table name is correct :)

Comment: I think its an error from my database it say Field 'tbl_users_users_id' doesn't have a default value

Answer (score 1):

Use this it's working now I have tested at local.

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $folder_path = 'health/';

    $filename = basename($_FILES['healthfile']['name']);
    $newname = $folder_path . $filename;

    if ($_FILES['healthfile']['type'] == "application/pdf")
    {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['healthfile']['tmp_name'], $newname))
        {

            $filesql = "INSERT INTO tbl_health (link) VALUES('$filename')";
            $fileresult = mysql_query($filesql);
        }
        else
        {

            echo "<p>Upload Failed.</p>";
        }

        if (isset($fileresult))
        {
            echo 'Success';
        } else
        {
            echo 'fail';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<p>Class notes must be uploaded in PDF format.</p>";
    }

}
?>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <label>Upload Your Health Certificate</label>
                <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                    Browse <input name="healthfile" type="file">
                </span>
            <br/><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn-success" value="submit">
        </form>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked but the file name doesn't save into the database

Comment: @Andrew you have to save file name and not full file. when you access the file give the path of that directory and fetch the file name from database.

Comment: @Andrew got it ? Make database connection then try it.

Comment: I have checked table name the field everything seems right

Comment: Have you make the database connection.

Comment: Can you send me a full file code. I have to check. my skype id deepaksaini6413

Comment: I have checked the error it say Field 'tbl_users_users_id' doesn't have a default value

Comment: Actually you are trying to insert data into a table and there is a field (tbl_users_users_id) you must fill out. You can't send a null value for this field.

Comment: but its a primary key

Comment: yeah it's primary key I think it's not auto increment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89873/discussion-between-deepak-saini-and-andrew).